# Enter key to create a new paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mw4c/1/

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".content", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pasteHtmlAtCaret('</p><p>');
    }
});


function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html){
    var sel, range;
    if(window.getSelection){
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if(sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount){
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();

            // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
            // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
            while((node = el.firstChild)){
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);

            // Preserve the selection
            if(lastNode){
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                range.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    }else if(document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control"){
        // IE < 9
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how I would accomplish the task of when someone press enter, it will jump out of the current `<p>` tag and start a new `<p>` tag, like in a wysiwyg editor. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**like this?**

```
$('p').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).after('</p><p>');
    }
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/5QXqH/

Comment: Thanks that works! Now I need to get it to remove the default text and make it an empty p tag when you click on the div

Comment: np, updated the fiddle to remove text. also added 2 css properties so the highlighted area stays highlighted even when the only `p` has no height or width.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a new `<p>` with your new content and append (or prepend) it to your `.content` container, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiattp/2mw4c/11/).

**View**

```
<div class="content"><p class="new-content" contenteditable="true">Click</p></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".content", function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $("p.new-content").text();
    $("<p>" + content + "</p>").insertBefore("p.new-content");
    $("p.new-content").text("");
  }
});

$(document).on("click", "p", function (e) {
  $("p.new-content").removeClass("new-content").attr("contenteditable",false);
  $(this).addClass("new-content").attr("contenteditable",true).focus();
});
```